# Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker environment: no entries in etc/hosts for lined containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an environment with a few containers. Some of them are linked. When I run the environment with "docker-compose up -d", it creates entries in etc/hosts for linked containers. When I run it with "eb local run", no entries are created. Why is that?

My Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
      "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
      "containerDefinitions": [
        {
          "name": "api",
          "image": "php7",
          "essential": true,
          "memory": 128,
          "portMappings": [
            {
              "hostPort": 8080,
              "containerPort": 80
            }
          ],
          "mountPoints": [
            {
              "sourceVolume": "api",
              "containerPath": "/var/www/html/"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "nodeapi",
          "image": "nodejs",
          "essential": true,
          "memory": 256,
          "portMappings": [
            {
              "hostPort": 5000,
              "containerPort": 5000
            }
          ],
          "mountPoints": [
            {
              "sourceVolume": "nodeapi",
              "containerPath": "/var/www/app/"
            }
          ],
          "Logging": "/var/eb_log"
        },
        {
          "name": "proxy",
          "image": "nginx",
          "essential": true,
          "memory": 128,
          "links": [
            "api",
            "nodeapi"
          ],
          "portMappings": [
            {
              "hostPort": 8443,
              "containerPort": 80
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This generates docker-compose.yml:

```
    api:
      image: php7
      ports:
      - 8080:80
    nodeapi:
      image: nodejs
      ports:
      - 5000:5000
    proxy:
      image: nginx
      links:
      - api:api
      - nodeapi:nodeapi
      ports:
      - 8443:80
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker switched to DNS based lookups a while back instead of adding entries to /etc/hosts. Linking is also discouraged in favor of using a common network for the containers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My docker version is 1.9.1. Are you saying that if I upgrade to the latest version links won't work any more when using docker-compose?

Comment: It's still an option, just not recommended going forward. DNS discovery was added in 1.10, released in February.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks. But do you know why EB Multicontainer Docker environment doesn't add aliases for those links to etc/hosts while docker-compose does?

Comment: I'm not sure of the AWS specific implementation, did you attempt to solve your problem with DNS yet?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is was a local issue. I upgraded Docker and EB cli to the latest versions and this solved the issue. I'm not sure why EB cli failed to add aliases to etc/hosts previously, but after upgrade it does. Now I get same results either by using "docker-compose up" or "eb local run". All linked container are linked now and work as expected.